# why require in node.js is order dependent?

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I am using require.js before, I think it is order independently. Now I am using node.js require, and I found it is order dependent, is this true? Is there any way to ensure order independently require?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js requires are blocking and synchronous.

If you `browserify` you can "preload" the modules you are using by running:

`browserify index.js --node -u '**.node' > bundle.js`